# MySQL Trigger / Federated Tables

Tags: mysql, triggers, federated

I'm struggling to achive this:

I have a mysql server A (w/c is a percona server) and a mysql server B (w/c is also a percona server)

In the mysql server a, I have this database proddb and a table export_transaction (this is an existing table with a 10000 records)
In the mysql server b, I also have this database prodb and a table export_transaction ( this is an empty table)

I want to create a trigger that if there is an update of the table in mysql server A export_transaction, it will also update the export_transaction in  mysql server B.

the mysql server A and mysql server B are two different servers, with a different ip address.

I wonder if this is possible.

Thank you in advanced.

I tried to implement my idea but it doesn't work with existing tables.
I have to recreate the existing table export_transaction in mysql server a.

CREATE TABLE prodb.export_transaction (
-- Define columns here
)
ENGINE = FEDERATED
CONNECTION = 'mysql://username@server_b_host:3306/prodb/export_transactions';

I don't want to create another server.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is nothing but a repetition of the tags. The title should be clear and descriptive enough to convey meaning about your post content to a future site user who is skimming a list of search results. Also, you'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: Why not use [replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html)?

Comment: @Bill Karwin Replication is the ideal choice. But if those are cloud service and end-user has no access to configure replication, are there any other ways? Do we have to resort to APP side ?

Comment: @blabla_bingo, Can you reference an example of a cloud vendor that does not allow configuring replication to or from external MySQL instances?

Comment: @Bill Karwin, My apologies, sir. I consulted the presales staff.  Though the MySQL cloud service they offer is a fully managed database service which does not grant os-level access , it does support table-level replication by using a service called Data Transmission Service (DTS), which supports data synchronization between two MySQL databases. P.S. I'm still learning from your book. Some solutions are really brilliant( In you words, *maybe too clever* ^^ ). I especially appriciate you trying to make the queries being vendor-neutral. I wonder if the volume 2 will be out in the near future?

Comment: Thanks for checking out my book! I'm glad you liked it. I am working on volume 2, slowly. I hope it'll be out next year.